# NoMethodError in Statuses#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error when I try running my ruby on rails application:

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#index

undefined method `full_name' for #<Status:0x3fe0e38>
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error, I would appreciate if someone could point out where I've gone wrong!

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>All Statuses</h1>
</div>

<%= link_to "Post A New Status", new_status_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% @statuses.each do |status| %> 
<div class="status">
  <strong><%= status.full_name %></strong>
  <p><%= status.content %></p></div>
  <div class="meta">
    <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at) + " ago", status %> 
    <span class="admin">
          | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_status_path(status) %> | 
          <%= link_to "Delete", status, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure  your want to delete this status?"} %>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
              :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :statuses

  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end
```

**statuses_controller.rb**

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @statuses }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/new
  # GET /statuses/new.json
  def new
    @status = Status.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = Status.new(params[:status])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /statuses/1
  # PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
     @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update_attributes(params[:status])
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @status.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: please add your index action of the users controller - or whatever controller you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling full_name on a status object, yet the method is defined in the user model. If you want the user's full name iterating through statuses you would do something like:

```
<%= status.user.full_name %>
```

assuming the association in Status exists for user

Answer (score 0):

Because a `Status` does not have a `full_name`.

Your `User` model does, but you do not appear to be attempting to display a user, rather the statuses. It appears each user has unique statuses, so you could just print the status's user's full name.

That said, unless you really need arbitrary statuses per user, normally you might have a status table, and related users to statuses with a join table, which would make this technique unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should be calling `full_name` on the `User` Object not the `Status` object.

```
<strong><%= status.user.full_name %></strong>
```

Assuming they both are associated (with a `belongs_to :user`), this should work.